# Using enum without attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

For backward compatibility on a rails 4.2 project, I am using the `protected_attributes` gem.  On a `User` model I have the following declaration

```
 enum access_level: [:general, :marketing, :admin]
```

If I try to do  `user.admin!`, I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: access_level
```

This can be solved by declaring

```
attr_accessible :access_level
```

but I do not want to allow the potential for users to give themselves admin role.  Is there a simple way that I can continue to use  `protected_attributes` gem and enums, and prevent users from granting themselves an admin role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround was as follows. I ensured that only the :admin role could do a mass assignment on `access_level`;

```
attr_accessible :access_level, as: :admin
```

then defined the following method

```
  def set_admin
    update({access_level: 2}, as: :admin)
  end
```

which was used instead of `admin!`. All the other read-only enum methods such as `admin?` or `Admin.admin` work. A similar method can be defined for the other enum possibilities.  When the app is upgraded to use strong_parameters, it should be easy to do a search and replace to use `admin!`.